# Allow normal users to authenticate with username or email, while keeping email authentication for admins in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) documentation for devise User login with username or password for normal users.
Then I added ActiveAdmin.
ran rails s and opened localhost:3000/admin/login 
this showed me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUZl9.png) error.

I fixed it by restoring my devise.rb file to default i.e. setting 
 config.authentication_keys = [ :login ] to  config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

now I can access localhost:3000/admin/login but my normal user login method is changed to login via email only, which I wanted to be like login via email or username

How to fix this?

Comment: `config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :login ] ` - but you have to actually add the login (or username) column to the users table.